# How can I push array to firebase as key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to store array at firebase but when I push array to firebase I get this :

[image: wrong node]

In here key values are indexes but I need this type of node

[image: needed node]

In here my code :

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('orders/kullanicilar')

rootRef.child(userId).child('eklenenUrunler').set({
    sepettekiUrunler
}).then(success => {
    console.log("succes");
});
```

How can I make it?

Comment: Problem is your data object. Create a object that including properties eklenenUrunler, sepettekiUrunler etc. Then save or update this data object on firebase.

Comment: I am new at js. Can you have any tutorials or how can I search that?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how `sepettekiUrunler` is initialized.

Comment: Your structure is doing exactly what your code says `child('eklenenUrunler')` is being set to `sepettekiUrunler` which has a 'sepettekiUrunler' as the documentId and then the array. If you don't want that structure, then don't do that - `eklenenUrunler` should be the documentId with the array. So something like `rootRef.child(userId).set({eklenenUrunler`